# how to write a correlated subquery in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, correlated-subquery

Can you please help me how to write a correlated sub query in snowflake?

```
select a
       b,
       (select d.x from d inner join b on d.id=b.id) As x,
       (select d.x from d inner join bon d.id!=b.id) AS Y  
FROM a 
inner join b on a.id=b.id
```

select X from d table based on join condition.select another column from same table based on another join condition
    **The above query almost my original scenario. can you help me how to write a same query in snowflake**

Comment: Please provide an example dataset and the result of the query you're expecting. But note that in the `SELECT` list you can only have subqueries that return EXACTLY ONE ROW each. I'm guessing that's not the case in your query. You can also consider a subquery like `SELECT d.x FROM d WHERE d.id=b.id`, that might help. But I don't see how this can work for both `=` and `!=`.

Comment: ok thanks@MarcinZukowski let me try it

Answer (score 2):

Correlated subqueries are generally a bad idea, since in many cases they result in one query per row, which won't scale.
If I'm reading your query correctly though, you could simply join `d` twice with different join conditions to get `x` and `y`.

```
select
    a.*,
    b.*,
    d1.x as x,
    d2.x as y
from
    a
    join
    b on a.id = b.id
    join
    d as d1 on d.id = b.id
    join
    d as d2 on d.id <> b.id
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. As of a year later, correlated subqueries are not supported in SELECT clauses - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-subqueries.html#types-supported-by-snowflake

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake supports [`LATERAL`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral), which is a different way to correlate (non-scalar) subqueries, so this should work for you:

```sql
SELECT a, b, x, y
FROM a
  JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT d.x FROM d JOIN b ON d.id = b.id) AS x (x)
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT d.x FROM d JOIN b ON d.id != b.id) AS y (y)
```